# How to show all invalid objects in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

Looking for the view I can list up all 'invalid' objects in PostgreSQL.
In Oracle, we can use dab_objects.status column but I'm not sure if there is a simple way to do such a thing in PostgreSQL.

Maybe, I can check the invalid indexes with below code.
How can I do that for other objects?

```
SELECT pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_class, pg_index 
WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false 
AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that you have to check anything else, since other objects cannot become invalid in PostgreSQL.

Oracle and PostgreSQL work quite differently in that respect:

- In Oracle, you can always `ALTER` an object (for example a table) even if there are dependent objects (for example views). The dependent objects then become invalid and have to be *recompiled*.
- In PostgreSQL, you cannot `ALTER` an object that has dependend objects in a way that renders these dependent objects invalid. You have to drop and recreate the dependent objects.

Invalid indexes can be left behind by a failed `CREATE INDEX` command.

Comment: Great explanation. Only index should be considered in this area. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbeI think I downvoted your answer by mistake.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Actually, I saw today, that I have downvoted the answer yesterday, and it is not allowing me to un-downvote as the vote is already locked and i can change my vote only if  the answer is edited, I want to un-downvote the asnwer as answer was useful to me. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Edited so you can do it.