# Object (Table, View ...) Status Metadata in Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, pg

Is it possible to query object (object being table, view, etc.) status in Postgres? In Oracle an equivalent query would be:

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       status
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'VIEW'
```

(returns VALID/INVALID in status column)

Please let me know. I've googled for this already, but have not found much.

Michael

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39120069/5315974

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39120069/5315974

Postgres does not let you break the view (RULE), eg:

```
t=# create table so183 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create view v183 as select i from so183;
CREATE VIEW
t=# alter table so183 alter COLUMN i type text using i::text;
ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view v183 depends on column "i"
```