# how to alter length of a table column used in views

Tags: database, postgresql, alter

i want to change length of a table column of postgresql database table.
this is the error :

```
ERROR: cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL: rule _RETURN on view av_viewname depends on column "orderref
```

is there way to to change column length without destroy views?

Comment: Please use plain text in this topic instead of an image somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Please [check this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114922/how-to-show-all-invalid-objects-in-postgresql) and then proceed for your alteration.

You cannot change your columns' size without dropping it. Yet, first you have to get the definition of your view.